# Get Category names from category_master table in another model's view

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I have two different tables:

**document_master**

```
doc_id

cat_id

doc_name
```

**category_master**

```
cat_id

cat_name

cat_desc
```

I want **cat_name** in dropdown of view file document model.
I have created model called *catmodel* which contains details of `category_master`. I have also created model of *docmodel* as well.

How I get category name in dropdown in view?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand is that, you will show the category dropdown based on the selected document. Am I correct?

If that so, you will need to query the categories based on the `cat_id` from the document model. I assume `cat_id` is a reference to document table.

You can use something like this,

```
$query = new Query;
$query->select(['category.*'])
->from('category')
->leftJoin('document', 'category.cat_id = document.cat_id');
```

The code above queries all the categories with `cat_id` equal to selected document `cat_id`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply @ekaj_03. 
i have resolved it via another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
step :1

Create a function in category module file

public function getcategories()
{
        return ArrayHelper::map(DocCatogories::find()->all(), 'catogory_id', 'catogory_name');
}

step :2

Create a function in category module or
public function getcategories(){
return array();
}


step :3
Write a following code for auto fill up drop down list in document view file.

<div class = "form-group">
        <label class = "col-sm-3 control-label" for = "catogory_id">Select Category</label>
        <div class = "col-sm-9">
            <?php
                $categories = new DocCatogories;
                echo $form->field($model, 'catogory_id')->dropDownList($categories->getcategories())->label(false);
            ?>
        </div>
</div>
```